# How to show image or anything else in Kendo grid title with React

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid

How can i add image instead of text in title in Kendo grid , I am using Kendo with react. I am following this link

https://www.telerik.com/forums/using-an-image-instead-of-text-in-title

But it seems to be not working.

I have added relevant code in componentWillMount method.

My code:

```
componentWillMount() {
     var header = $("#grid .k-grid-header thead");
        header
            //finds the corresponding field based on grid field titles
            .find("[data-field=''] a.k-link")
                //modifies inner HTML
                .html('<div style='display: inline;text-align:center;font-size: 20px;margin-right: 10px;' id='' class='fa fa-angle-up btnUp'></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for Kendo UI React components which you can find [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/).

And in component you can do like follow.

```
render(){
  let title = <img src="" /> //your image url
  return(
      <Grid
        style={{ height: '400px' }}
        data={this.state.gridData}
        resizable={true}
       >
         <GridColumn field="name" title={title} width="45px" />
      </Grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, that is giving me reference error as I am adding columns as constant and not directly in render. I see , there is one attribute : headerAttributes by which we can define style and class for column header but i need to add a div or image.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used "headerTemplate" of Kendo grid to add a div for column header.

```
    {
        field: "id",
        title: " ",
        width: 23,
        template: '<input type="checkbox" class="select-row" />',
        headerTemplate:"<div style='' id='' class=''></div>"
    }
```